# Filter table with KnockoutJS

Tags: knockout.js

I am loading a list of stores and I want to add a filter input that when I start typing, it filters the table data. I have the code for displaying the data but not sure on how to build the filter. Could someone link to a tutorial to explain this or at least get me started? The code can be seen at CodePen http://codepen.io/jrock2004/pen/rVQaGM

**Jade**

```
block content
.container(role="main")
.row
  .col-md-12
    div.col-md-1
      span Filter:
    div.col-md-3
      input.form-control
    div.col-md-12.store-table
      table.table.table-bordered.table-striped.table-condensed
        thead
          tr
            th Store Store Name
            th Wiki Locations
            th DB Locations
            th Sites
        tbody(data-bind="foreach:stores")
          tr
            td(data-bind="text: store_name")
            td
              ul
                li
                  a(data-bind="attr: { href: store_wiki_folder }") Store Folder
                li
                  a(data-bind="attr: { href: store_wiki_contact }") Contact Folder
                li
                  a(data-bind="attr: { href: store_wiki_access }") Access Folder
            td(data-bind="text: store_db")
            td
              dl(data-bind="foreach: sites")
                dt(data-bind="text: label")
                dd
                  a(data-bind="attr: { href: label_link }, text: label_link", target="_blank")
                  a(data-bind="attr: { href: special_link }, text: special_label", target="_blank")
```

**JS**

```
var storeObj = [
{
"store_name": "Aber",
"store_wiki_folder": "#F",
"store_wiki_contact": "#C",
"store_wiki_access": "#A",
"store_db": "db:127.2.3.1:9000",
"sites": [{
  "label": "Prod",
  "label_link": "http://google.com",
  "special_label": "[Admin]",
  "special_link": "http://images.google.com"
}, {
  "label": "Train",
  "label_link": "http://google.com",
  "special_label": "[Admin]",
  "special_link": "http://images.google.com"
}]
},
{
"store_name": "Acad",
"store_wiki_folder": "#F",
"store_wiki_contact": "#C",
"store_wiki_access": "#A",
"store_db": "db:127.2.3.1:9000",
"sites": [{
  "label": "Live",
  "label_link": "http://google.com",
  "special_label": "[Admin]",
  "special_link": "http://images.google.com"
}, {
  "label": "Test",
  "label_link": "http://google.com",
  "special_label": "[Admin]",
  "special_link": "http://images.google.com"
}]
},
{
"store_name": "Bear",
"store_wiki_folder": "#F",
"store_wiki_contact": "#C",
"store_wiki_access": "#A",
"store_db": "db:127.2.3.1:9000",
"sites": [{
  "label": "Prod",
  "label_link": "http://google.com",
  "special_label": "[Admin]",
  "special_link": "http://images.google.com"
}, {
  "label": "Train",
  "label_link": "http://google.com",
  "special_label": "[Admin]",
  "special_link": "http://images.google.com"
}]
},
{
"store_name": "Cool Kids",
"store_wiki_folder": "#F",
"store_wiki_contact": "#C",
"store_wiki_access": "#A",
"store_db": "db:127.2.3.1:9000",
"sites": [{
  "label": "Prod",
  "label_link": "http://google.com",
  "special_label": "[Admin]",
  "special_link": "http://images.google.com"
}, {
  "label": "Train",
  "label_link": "http://google.com",
  "special_label": "[Admin]",
  "special_link": "http://images.google.com"
}]
},
];

var storesModel = ko.mapping.fromJS(storeObj);
ko.applyBindings({
stores: storesModel
});
```

Comment: You'll bind the input value to an observable, and make a computed that applies that value to filter the stores. It's not clear how you want the filter to work, exactly, or where you want to see the filtered results.

Comment: What I want is as I type and find matches to remove the rows from the table that do not match

Comment: I updated the code pen to databind and add filter value but now my table is broken

Comment: possible duplicate of [Filter Table Contents](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31188583/filter-table-contents)

Comment: So I looked that over and the observablearray is simple. Put updated code at http://codepen.io/jrock2004/pen/rVQaGM . I am getting closer

Comment: I've modified yours to do the filtering. http://codepen.io/anon/pen/KprwjM

Comment: @RoyJ could I make it a lazy search or does it have to be match?

Comment: You can do anything you want inside the computed. However you want to match is fine.